# Discolored Tzitzis

Tags: rambam, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, color, tallit-katan

The Rambam says that the tzitzis strings must be the same color as the garment they're attached to (with exception to the techeiles string which is always blue). (Source?)

All of the tallisos these days are predominantly white, and so the strings are also white. In the light of the Rambam's ruling, though, what would be the halacha on strings that became discolored over time or through some other accident?

For instance, Chaim Yankel ties white strings onto his white garment, and over time the strings become yellowed but the garment stays white. Or, someone accidently spills red paint and gets some on his tzitzis. Are the tzitzis still valid, even though they aren't the same color anymore?

Obviously not everyone agrees with the idea that the tzitzis should be the same color as the garment they're attached to, but this is a hypothetical idea following the Rambam's view.

Comment: Yellowed wool and white wool are almost certainly close enough to each other. It can't literally have to be 100% indistinguishable

Comment: @DoubleAA - You haven't seen the tzitzis I use for work. :)

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is a dupe, but I can't seem to find the question I was thinking of.

Comment: FWIW the majority of poskim hold that לבן actually means לבן=white, rather than לבן="the colour of the beged"

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Which is why I said "according to the Rambam." Other Rishonim hold differently, especially Ashkenazi ones.

Comment: I hold like the Rambam lechumrah, although I can't see why I'd get a non-white beged (other than an aged tallis, which is pattur from being viewed as colourful IIRC)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - So it's as if you aren't holding by him at all. What an easy chumrah to take on! :P ;)

Comment: I think that the general practice is that we only wear white begadim (with whatever colour stripes) lichvodo, even if he's not the shitta we hold like.

Comment: See R' Herschel Schachter here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38052/4504